Wiremock returns real response when calling API endpoints instead of stubs?
I'm working on a project which will be used as a maven dependency for an other project. We're building stubs and using wiremock. I noticed that even though we stubbed several endpoints, the response body contains real response of the service after text execution, instead of the response jsonbody of our stubs. The weird thing is that these stubs are working, since they are being mapped correctly - I know it, because if I put a mistake in the URL or urlPathPattern, then the request won't be matched, and the test fails at this point.
But, even if the pattern is correct, the real service response will be logged on the terminal, and not the stubs' response jsonbody. How can I fix this? I would like to log the stubs response, not the real service.

Can you provide an example of your test, including how you're setting up WireMock and the stubs?
